# Is it possible to know if an animated SVG's drawn path has left the viewport?

Tags: svg, fullpage.js, gsap

I have a long SVG of 'threads' that are a graphical element joining multiple Fullpage.js horizontal slides together. (it's a story, so it makes sense for the design)

At the moment, when the user lands on the page and the first slide is rendered, the SVG dashoffset is animated with GSAP to draw the path, which looks great on the first slide.

However, when you change to the next slide the path is already there. If I time it right, and I move onto the next slide with the animation, it looks 100000% better with the thread continuing the animation of the path.

So long story short, is it possible to start the animation on slide 1, then pause it when the path leaves the viewport, then unpause it to continue the animation when the second slide is in sliding across into view?

Comment: Hey Jay. This sort of thing is definitely possible but it depends fully on how your animation and page is setup. Most likely it's easiest to use multiple animations that play portions of what is currently one animation. Past that we can't really help you with the information given.

Comment: @ZachSaucier That makes sense. I thought about breaking up the SVG into portions, but where it's a responsive page, the breakpoint where the SVG is on the next slide would differ across all sizes.

Comment: I see. Detecting where it should stop is not necessarily trivial either, especially if the graphical element is not purely linear. I still think your best bet is splitting up the animation/SVG per slide and doing your best to size it appropriately. But again with no code to see it's hard to give finite advice.

Comment: Some APIs I would look into to do this: [AnimationEffect.getComputedTiming().progress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnimationEffect/getComputedTiming) to find out where you are in your animation, compute where the `stroke-dashoffset` currently is along the path length provided by [GeometryElement.getTotalLength()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getTotalLength), locate that point with [GeometryElement.getPointAtLength()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getPointAtLength)

Comment: You can pass percentages to the drawSVG plugin, could you set up an array of percentages to pause the svg at then restart from that value when you hit the next slide.
For example: `TweenMax.fromTo(lines, 1.5, {drawSVG: '0%'}, {drawSVG: '100%', ease: Power2.easeInOut});`

Answer (score 0):

fullPage.js provides the `onLeave` and `afterLoad` callbacks.
This way you get access to both states you mentioned:

- Leaving the slide (onLeave)
- Landing into a new slide. (afterLoad)

For more info on how to use this fullPage.js callbacks you can check [this example](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/XbPNQv) and the docs:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks

Comment: The Fullpage JS part isn't really the issue for this problem. It's more how to measure the visible length of an SVG in the viewport to only partially draw an SVG path. Thanks though.